# C++ Lambda Predicate Cause Variable Canot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

Tags: c++, lambda

This is function defintion

```
    template<typename Iter, typename T>
Iter lower_bound(Iter left, Iter right, const T& value){
    while (left < right){
        auto mid = std::next(left, std::distance(left, right)/2);
        if (*mid < value){
            left = std::next(mid);
        }else{
            right = mid;
        }

    }
    return left;
}



    template<typename Iter, typename T, typename Predicate>
Iter binary_search2(Iter left, Iter right, const T& value, Predicate funct){
    auto it = my::lower_bound(left, right, value);
    if (it != right && funct(*it)){
        return it;
    }else{
        return right;
    }
}
```

funct should be something like {return *it == value};
So I figure I would use a lambda function in the main method as follows:

```
 auto searchValue = 10;

int comparisons = 0;  // see how many comparison made

auto iter = my::binary_search2(std::begin(data), std::end(data), searchValue, [&comparisons](int& num){
++comparisons;
return num == searchValue;
```

});

I get a strange error "searchValue' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified"

Any ideas?

Comment: Explicitly capturing `searchValue` might be an idea.

Comment: @BrownBear2018 has your question been answered? You may tick an answer, if so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `[&comparisons]` you can write `[&]` to specify that we want to implicitly capture things by reference by default.

Otherwise you might write it explicitly. `[&comparisons, &searchValue]`

Because until you do one of those things, the compiler cannot know if you intended capture by value for searchValue. (`[=]`)

Answer (score 0):

Think of a lambda like

```
auto x = [](int a) -> int {
    return a + 2;
};
```

as something like

```
struct Lambda {
   int operator()(int a) const{
       return a + 2;
   }
};
```

Here

```
x(1) == Lambda{}(1) // == 3
```

Now, if one wants to capture an extra variable from outside the lambda context as:

```
int y = 5;
auto x = [y](int a) -> int {
    return a + y;
};
```

That's roughly equivalent to

```
struct Lambda {
    explicit Lambda2(int y): y(y){}
    int operator()(int a) const{
        return a + y;
    }
    private:
    int y;
};
```

Hence, now

```
x(1) == Lambda{y} // == 6
```

The second case is what is called the *Capturing Lambda* because, well... it *captures* variables from outside its scope. One needs to provide the lambda (or the roughly equivalent struct) the list of variables it needs to capture for later use when it shall be invoked.

There are many [ways to capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) variables. For your question, one approach could be to capture the variable by value since it's a plain integer

```
auto iter = my::binary_search2(std::begin(data), std::end(data), searchValue, 
    [&comparisons, searchValue](int& num){
    ++comparisons;
    return num == searchValue;
});
```

A copy of the variable `searchValue` is passed. Which is something like how the second Version of `struct Lambda` used.

Another way would be to capture it by reference in case `searchValue` was a variable that had an expensive copy or one wanted to modify it in the lambda body. [This is roughly equivalent to passing in a reference to the constructor of `struct Lambda`]

```
auto iter = my::binary_search2(std::begin(data), std::end(data), searchValue, 
    [&comparisons, &searchValue](int& num){
    ++comparisons;
    return num == searchValue;
});
```

If you want to capture by reference but don't want it to be modified in the lambda body then one can do something like

```
auto iter = my::binary_search2(std::begin(data), std::end(data), searchValue, 
    [&comparisons, &constSV = std::as_const(searchValue)](int& num){
    ++comparisons;
    return num == constSV;
});
```

by using the [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) to obtain a const reference to the captured variable. This is equivalent to passing in a `const&` to the constructor of `struct Lambda`.

These are some of the capture types that can be used.

Comment: Any idea why comparisons was not updated?   When I ran the code after adding comparison to be captured by reference.      auto it = std::find_if(std::cbegin(data), cend(data), [&searchValue, &comparisons](const int& item){
    ++comparisons;
    return item == searchValue ;

 });

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/5899qPTsf). Is your final code any different?